# How to navigate two urls at the same time using lightning component code

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to navigate two urls one after another using lightning component code,I am in Lightning Experience,I want to go Classic printable view page

My tried code:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

     <div>
        <div>
            <lightning:button label="Print" onclick="{!c.navigate}" class="print-hide" />

        </div>

    </div>  
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
}
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {

     var printoption = component.get("v.recordId");

   var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url":'https://domainname/ltng/switcher?destination=classic'
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url":'https://domainname'+printoption+'/p?retURL=/'+printoption
    });
    urlEvent.fire();

}
})
```

How to Navigate two urls at the same time one after another using lightning component code?

Comment: hm, do you want to open two new pages simultaneously ?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy,one new page only ,first classic url redirecting that page and after that classic printable view page,not two pages, only one new page

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy ,is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.OfCourse. It is possible with the for loop.Here is my test code.

Cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <lightning:button label="press" type="brand" onclick="{!c.doInit}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var list = ['https://www.google.co.in/','https://www.gmail.com'];
        for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            console.log(list[i])
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url":list[i]
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }
    }
})
```

Just replace the list with your URL's. It's works Fine.

Comment: ,no it is not working

Comment: ,if i click the button, it will open google.com page and after that navigate popup is occuring in lightining page,if we click it is openining in another new page,both the urls have to open in single page